# How to call multiple rest api one by one in loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsmutableurlrequest

I am trying get data from server to store locally when needed. The data is present at different api urls. I want to call all those apis on a single refresh click.Kindly help me to solve this.

```
-(void) call:(NSString *)url{

            NSURLRequest *Request1 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL :[NSURL URLWithString:url] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:30.0];
            // calling only one api
            NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:Request1 delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
            //            flag = true;
            [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Wait while we fetch data .."];
            if (connection){
                NSLog(@"connection success");
            }
            else{
                // handle error here
            }

}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Also your question is a bit vague as how and what you want to achieve.

Comment: please provide info what you want to do on refresh click

Comment: i am working on a project which needs to refresh its data in every 5 minutes and i have many api url to get data according to it so my ques is how do i call those url together so i get response one by one.

Comment: @vaibhav Please check the below answer and Let me know your feedback.

Comment: @ravindhrian sure your ans will call multiple api but how do i classify the diff response ..